# write() got multiple values for keyword argument 'context'

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm overriding the write() method

My code is

```
def write(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    for att in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        prev_att_ids = self.search(cr, uid, [('employee_id', '=', att.employee_id.id), ('name', '<', att.name),('action', 'in', ('sign_in', 'sign_out'))], limit=1, order='name DESC')
        next_add_ids = self.search(cr, uid, [('employee_id', '=', att.employee_id.id), ('name', '>', att.name),('action', 'in', ('sign_in', 'sign_out'))], limit=1, order='name ASC')
        prev_atts = self.browse(cr, uid, prev_att_ids, context=context)
        next_atts = self.browse(cr, uid, next_add_ids, context=context)
            if prev_atts and prev_atts[0].action == att.action:
                return self.write(cr, uid, ids, {'state': True})
            if next_atts and next_atts[0].action == att.action: # next exists and is same action
                return self.write(cr, uid, ids, {'state': True})
            if (not prev_atts) and (not next_atts) and att.action != 'sign_in': # first attendance must be sign_in
                return self.write(cr, uid, ids, {'state': True})
            else:
                return self.write(cr, uid, ids, {'state': False})
     return True
```

This is my code.

While executing it should check the three "if condition" and want to change the value of the field "state" either "true or false" according to the "if conditions".

But the problem is, When I execute this code it show this error

> ValidateError Error while validating constraint write() got multiple
>   values for keyword argument 'context'

How can I solve this issue? Help me

Thanks

Comment: Where does `write` come from?

Comment: What is the signature of the original method?

Comment: It is odoo v8 write() method used to save the records in the database. I'm making changes in the attendance module of odoo

Comment: There are in Odoo `def write(self, vals):` and `def _write(self, cr, user, ids, vals, context=None):`. There isn't `def write(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):`. If you want to overwrite it, you should use the same input parameters